# kotlin:convert string to int to calculate values

Tags: string, kotlin, math, calculation

I am building an app that brings an html values(numbers) using jsoup.I saved values in a StringBuilder variable to append data to it.After retrieving values,I'll use them to make a calculation to get net result.
The problem is that when i try to convert stringbuilder variable to string then to int,i got  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` .
i tested string before converting it,and it works normally and it has a value.

example:

```
var init_recent_price=StringBuilder()
var v1=init_recent_price.toString()
var v2=inv_amount[index].toDouble().roundToInt().toString()
new_amount=(v1.toDouble().roundToInt()+v2.toDouble().roundToInt()).toString()
```

My question: how can i convert any string or StringBuilder to be Int or Float to accept arithmetic calculation.

`Note:` I must use String or StringBuilder in my code,and not `Int` or any primitive types,becuause i use `lateinit` modifier that doesn't accept primitive types

Comment: This might be an http://xyproblem.info/. When you want something like `lateinit` for primitives, you can use `var x: Int by Delegates.notNull()`. Or in some applications, you can simply initialize it with 0 or a negative value to indicate it's not ready. Storing numbers in a String is very error-prone and difficult to read.

Comment: As for your code above, you never put a number in the string for `v1` so it cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: `Int` is not necessarily a primitive type.  (The compiler may implement it with the primitive `int` or the object `java.lang.Integer`, depending how it's used.  And nullable `Int?` will always be the latter.)